# Vault standby mode still sealed after the active mode server was unsealed

Tags: consul, hashicorp-vault

I have following this tutorial: https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/operations/ops-vault-ha-consul

and make it same but using different IP addresses. but when I tried to unseald the active node, the standby mode still sealed.

I just wondering that from documentation said, if we are active HA we are just need to unseal it from 1 node and the rest will be activated automaticaly. *CMIIW*

this is from active node that was did `sealed`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-227:~$ vault status
Key             Value
---             -----
Seal Type       shamir
Initialized     true
Sealed          false
Total Shares    5
Threshold       3
Version         1.0.0
Cluster Name    vault-cluster-762abd6d
Cluster ID      ad4a8558-de0d-2b4b-6212-28ab1827fa88
HA Enabled      true
HA Cluster      https://172.31.2.227:8201
HA Mode         active
ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-227:~$
```

and this is from `standby node`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-175:~$ vault status
Key                Value
---                -----
Seal Type          shamir
Initialized        true
Sealed             true
Total Shares       5
Threshold          3
Unseal Progress    0/3
Unseal Nonce       n/a
Version            1.0.0
HA Enabled         true
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-175:~$
```

Am I missed a thing when reading the documentation ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From that guide

> Now youâll need to move on to initializing and unsealing each Vault instance.

Emphasis on the `each`.

You'll need to unseal each node separately. This is by design, so that no rogue node can join the cluster if its not authorised to do so (and you authorise a node by giving it the unseal keys).